# Getting undefined because of asynchronous calling

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, return, synchronous

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I'm working on a backend on NodeJS for a Sencha Touch app and at some point I'm calling a function, but I'm getting to next line of code before getting that functions return statement.

Here's my code...

```
.... for loop ....
        if(resultSet[k].id_bus == busDocs[n].id_bus && resultSet[k].id_bus_variation == busDocs[n].id_bus_variation){
            resultSet[k].s_origin_description = busDocs[n].s_origin_description;
            resultSet[k].s_eta = vehicle != null ? getVehicleETA(db, vehicle) : 'Unknown';
            console.log('after getting eta');
            resultSet[k].s_destination_description = busDocs[n].s_destination_description;
        }
    }
}
res.send(JSON.stringify(resultSet));
....
```

and this is my getVehicleETA function...

```
getVehicleETA = function(db, vehicle){
    var position = vehicle.position;

    function compare(a,b) {
      if (a.n_stop_number < b.n_stop_number)
         return -1;
      if (a.n_stop_number > b.n_stop_number)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    db.get('busstops').find({$query:{$and:[{id_bus: vehicle.id_bus}, {id_bus_variation: vehicle.id_bus_variation}]},$orderBy:{n_stop_number: 1}},function(e, docs){
        var distance = 0;
        if(docs.length != 0){
            docs.sort(compare);
            var nextBusStop = null;
            for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++){
                if(i+1 < docs.length){
                    var routeSegmentLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(docs[i +1].coord_x - docs[i].coord_x, 2) + Math.pow(docs[i +1].coord_y - docs[i].coord_y, 2));
                    var firstStopDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vehicle.coord_x - docs[i].coord_x, 2) + Math.pow(vehicle.coord_y - docs[i].coord_y, 2));
                    var secondStopDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vehicle.coord_x - docs[i +1].coord_x, 2) + Math.pow(vehicle.coord_y - docs[i +1].coord_y, 2));
                    if(nextBusStop != null){
                        distance += routeSegmentLength;
                    }

                    if(secondStopDistance < routeSegmentLength && firstStopDistance < routeSegmentLength){    
                        nextBusStop = docs[i+1];
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(((distance/(1000 * vehicle.speed)) * 60))
            return ((distance/(1000 * vehicle.speed)) * 60);
        }
    });
}
```

If this was working correctly I would have to see `getVehicleETA`'s `console.log` first, and then `console.log('after getting eta');` but I'm getting it the other way around. I know this is actually correct behaviour as it didn't block the thread and kept going on in the code, but this is not working for me, because I'm sending the resultSet before even getting my `getVehicleETA` result, and I need `resultSet`'s items to have it's `s_eta` property set before sending them.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is to have a callback in getVehicleETA function.

Let me show you as an illustration:

```
getVehicleETA = function(db,vehicle,callback){
    /*do some stuff*/
    //return the result in callback.
    callback(result); 
}

resultSet[k].s_origin_description = busDocs[n].s_origin_description;
if(vehicle!=null){
    getVehicleETA(db,vehicle,function(result){
        resultSet[k].s_eta = result;            
        nextAction()
    });
}else{
    resultSet[k].s_eta = "unknown";
    nextAction();
}

function nextAction (){
    console.log('after getting eta');
    resultSet[k].s_destination_description = busDocs[n].s_destination_de
    res.send(JSON.stringify(resultSet));
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling an asynchronous function as if it were synchronous. Also, returning a value from a callback for an asynchronous function is meaningless. You have to pass in a callback to the function and then call that callback within your database callback with the values from the database.

You should look into using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) module to help you handle asynchronous function calls in a loop.

Comment: isn't async frowned upon?

Comment: @lascort No, it's actually a fairly popular module that's used in quite a lot of projects (including outside of npm). It currently has 1000 dependents on [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) though.